# How to bring iOS rootviewcontroller to the foreground

Tags: ios7

I'm calling a method in AppDelegate from a modal view to switch to rootviewcontroller (TabBarController) after an event occurs. How can I bring the rootview to the foreground? I shouldn't create a new instance of rootviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the instance of the applications rootViewController using self.window.rootViewController

Comment: Thanks Matt. I could access the root view controller with self.window.rootViewController. I realized that there is a modalview that got presented by rootviewcontroller and I need to dismiss it to make the root view appear. My root view controller is a UITabBarController. When I call [mainTabBar setSelectedIndex:1];
    [mainTabBar dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];, the root view comes to the foreground but dismissModalViewControllerAnimated is deprecated. And using dismissViewController doesn't help.